# Windows command line for Disk Space usage report - sub directory level

Tags: windows, cmd, diskspace

Is there any windows command which can be used with cmd prompt to check for disk space use. The report should be detailed in terms of sizes in GB i.e. list out folders with size greater than 1

Also, I wouldn't prefer to use any third party tool. There are restrictions of using any third party software in the particular machine. So a cmd line command would be the best solution.

Comment: Is it OK to use the windows ressource kit ? If  so look at `diruse.exe` http://ss64.com/nt/diruse.html

Comment: Thanks Kayasax. I used D:\>DISKUSE /v /s /x:100000000 /d /t which seems to provide a good enough report for me.                                              I am still open for other simple command line suggestions.

Comment: I don't think you're going to beat `DISKUSE` for simplicity, but the `du` module from [sysinternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896651) will do what you want and is, arguably, not a third-party tool (but does require a download).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to write a custom PowerShell, VBScript, or JScript solution easily enough.

Or you could use my [JREN.BAT utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081) - a hybrid JScript/batch script that is designed to rename files/folders via regular expressions, but it has a /LIST option that can be used to provide custom directory listings. JREN.BAT is pure script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

Assuming you have JREN.BAT somewhere within your PATH, then the following command will list folders on the D:\ drive that are at least 1000000000 bytes (decimal GB) in size. Note that the reported size of each folder includes the size of all its children. So if a child is greater than 1GB, then its parent is guaranteed to also be greater than 1GB.

```
jren "^.*" "lpad((size()/1000000000).toFixed(3),'        ')+'  '+path()" /s /d /j /list /p "D:\" | findstr /rvc:"^ *0"
```

The JREN command lists each foder size in GB, followed by the full path. I pipe that to FINDSTR to filter out folders that are smaller than 1GB.

Given that JREN.BAT is a bat file, you must prefix the command with CALL if you want to use it in a batch script.

There are lots of options to specify the root path, exclusion lists, path masks, etc. Full documentation is embedded within the utility.

I believe there is a bug in the current version that causes the command to fail when it tries to access the size of a folder that it does not have access to. I may fix that when I get a chance.